# copy images from python server to php server

Tags: php, python

On my python/django server I have a table in my database records with the link to existing images like 'image/5qsd48zera5.jpg','image/qsd454f5sdf.jpg'.

How I can I copy those images to an other server which runs php? Can/should I copy trough SSH2, ftp, ...?

Comment: What do you want to do? To have the images somewhere else or to have the table available? If you want to move or copy the images, it depends on what is available at the php-server-end. personally, I would use scp or rsync and only if neither of those are available I would use ftp.

Comment: I want to copy the image files to the other server! The Python server is Windows 7 (64bit); can I use scp or rsync on Windows?

Comment: both of them exist on windows. for scp you probably want the putty-package: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: Can I schedule such thing to check for new/updated images every hour?

Comment: I have never tried it, but it should be no problems running that through the normal windows scheduling service. (I am in a linux-only place now, so I cannot test it) If you set it up with a key pair using a key without pass-phrase, it can run completely unattended (but then you want to restrict what the user can do at the "php-server-side" and make sure the personal key is stored in a place where is hard for others to get hold of it...)

Comment: Oh and then rsync (possibly over ssh so you can use public-key authentication) may be a better idea, since that has a build in possibility to only copy new or changed files.

Comment: it says here ( https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync ): "You must, however, have a working ssh system." What does that mean?

Comment: I made a more specific question based on your comments:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701092/how-to-copy-files-from-my-server-to-an-external-server-with-cwrsync